# More efficient way to iterate through an array of NSStrings and compare them

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, nsstring

I'm just looking for a nicer and more efficient way to iterate through a given array of objects and compare a `NSString` property of each to another array just containing NSStrings.

My current code uses two for-each loops but it don't think that it is the most efficient way.

```
for (MYClass *foo in arrayOfMyClass) {
    for (NSString *ID in arrayOfStringIDs) {
        if ([foo.Id isEqualToString:ID]) {
            //Do something
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I think that it should be somehow possible to drop at least one loop with some cool tricks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want to know is if `foo.Id` exists in `arrayOfStringIDs`, use an NSSet of strings instead. Then you can do:

```
NSSet * mySetOfStringIDs = [NSSet setWithArray:arrayOfStringIDs];
for(MyClass * foo in arrayOfMyClass) {
    if([mySetOfStringIDs containsObject:foo.Id]) {
        // Do something
        break;
    }
}
```

This avoids the second loop, since `containsObject:` is generally much faster than O(n) for a set. You should, of course, do your own profiling as needed.

Comment: Is this actually faster than a second loop?
I mean, what does containsObject: do? I'm just curious.

Comment: I can't say for sure, since the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is pretty sparse. The optimized algorithm for this kind of collection, though, would store objects using a hash of some kind, then rely on using the hash of the object you pass to quickly look up whether a matching object already exists in the set. Usually, this is done in O(1) on average.

Comment: Reading more through the docs, you might also consider using `member:` instead of `containsObject:` if the latter gives you trouble; `member:` is documented to explicitly use `isEqual:`, which has a pretty close relation with `hash` for objects that implement it.

Comment: Very interesting. I definitely don't have any performance problems, because the string array has just a few (4~5) items and other array just about 100 but i'm still curious.

Comment: Can isEqual: actually work? Because the string is not really the same string. The letters are js equal but the pointers are something completely different. Or does NSString override the isEqual method with isEqualToString: ?

Comment: NSString (along with most other framework classes where it makes sense) overrides `isEqual:` with an appropriate implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Check for indexofobject method of Nsarray. May be it can help you to get the index directly instead of a loop for the string in nsarray.

Comment: No, because i have to try each object in that array.

Comment: indexofobject will also do the same way. it will check the given objects index without going into loop.

Comment: Now i understand what you mean. Yes that is also a valid aproach.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an array of strings that exist in both `arrayOfMyClass` and `arrayOfStringIDs` then you could use key-value coding to pull the set of strings out of `arrayOfMyClass` and intersect the resulting set with `arrayOfStringIDs`. If your class is KVC compliant then you can get all the `Id` strings out of it as a set:

```
NSMutableSet *idSet=[NSMutableSet setWithArray:[arrayOfMyClass 
   valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.Id"]];
[idSet intersectSet:[NSSet setWithArray:arrayOfStringIDs]];
NSArray *idArray=[idSet allObjects];
```

Unfortunately there is not a method to intersect two `NSArray`s which is why they have to be turned into a set first.